# Make a form_for add data to existing model (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model with name password and phone_number. On user creation I ask for email and password but I need a form on **another** page to add phone number!

I tried this:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.label :phone_number
  = f.text_field :phone_number 
  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

Problem with this is that it hits the user update which asks for password_reset:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def update
  if current_user
    @user = current_user
  else
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  end
  @user.password_hash = nil
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to @user, :notice => "Password has been changed!"
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, isn't it updated correctly? what's password_reset?

Comment: Roy!! What's up lol. Yes the password reset works fine but I'm simply trying to get it to add the phone_number in a new form. When I submit I get the error 'password can't be blank'

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a way to make the user update also add phone_number when on that page

Comment: ah right, then bigxiang answer below should be correct :)
basically when the form contain password it will remove @user.password_hash but if not it will be simple update_attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can decide the update action based on params.

```
def update
  if current_user
    @user = current_user
  else
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  if params[:user][:password]
    # or other actions will save new password?
    @user.password_hash = nil
    notice = "Password has been changed!"
  else
    notice = "User profile has been changed!"
  end

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to @user, :notice => notice
  else
    render "edit"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store edited phone number in session, then read it when your main editing form is submitted

Answer (score 1):

On your first form you can get the details of **email and password** and when you submit the form don't create user record instead store email and password into **flash[:user]={:email => "given email", :password => "given password"}**(Flash will automatically reset once it is redirected to next page, so for this case flash would be better than session but go for session if you want to have a Back option on your second form) and then redirect to your second form.

On your second form you can get the details of **phone number** along with that **add two hidden fields email and password** which you can fill the value from flash[:user] or session[:user].  When you submit your second form you can create a new user where your params[:user] should have email, password and phone_number.